# How to submit a Django form using JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, submit, form-submit

I'm working on a web app project. I had a problem with file upload. Then I realized that my team mate changed the default submit button in **create_form.html**. It works like in **5.** and **6.** and i need to collect file data as well.

What should I add to .js files to submit and save file?

1. **forms.py**

   ```
   class DocumentUpload(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Form
           fields = ('file',)
   ```
2. **models.py**

   ```
   class Form(TimeStampedModel, TitleSlugDescriptionModel):
       author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
       is_final = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       is_result_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.title

       def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('form-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
   ```
3. **views.py**

   ```
   def create_form(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           user = request.user
           data = ParseRequest(request.POST)
           print(data.questions())
           print(data.form())
           parsed_form = data.form()
           parsed_questions = data.questions()

           # tworzy formularz o podanych parametrach
           formfile = DocumentUpload(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
           if formfile.is_valid():
               form = formfile.save(commit=False)
               print(form)
               form.author = user
               form.title = parsed_form['title']
               form.is_final = parsed_form['is_final']
               form.is_result_public = parsed_form['is_result_public']
               form.description = parsed_form['description']
               form.save()
               # zapisuje pytania z ankiety wraz z odpowienimi pytaniami
               for d in parsed_questions:
                   question = Question(form=form, question=d['question'])
                   question.save()
                   # dla kazdego pytania zapisz wszystkie opcje odpowiadania
                   for opt in d['options']:
                       option = Option(question=question, option=opt)
                       option.save()
               return render(request, 'forms/form_form.html', {})
       else:
           form = DocumentUpload()
           return render(request, 'forms/form_form.html', {'form': form})
   ```
4. **create_form.html**

   Here I have to submit `{{ form.as_p }}` <- I have to submit this input in JS**

   ```
       {% block content %}
       <form method="post" id="form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
       {%csrf_token %}
       <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="form-title">Tytuł formularza</label>
            <input id="form-title" class="form-control" type="text" 
                                     placeholder="Tytuł" required/>
        </div>
        {{ form.as_p }}

        .... more divs ...

       <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="zapisz"/>
       </form>
       {% endblock %}
   ```
5. **collect_data.js**

   This is my function called to save inputs from `create_form.html` instead of:

   ```
   <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="zapisz"/>
   ```

   but I don't know how to save input from:

   ```
   {{ form.as_p }}  

    function collect_data() {
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    var data = {
        form_title: $('#form-title').val(),
        is_final: $('#form-is-final').prop('checked'),
        is_public: $('#form-is-public').prop('checked'),
        is_result_public: $('#form-is-result-public').prop('checked'),
        description: $('#description').val(),
        questions: [],
        num_questions: num_questions,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
    };
    for (var k = 0; k < num_questions; k++) {
       var my_data = {};
       var question_k = $('#question-' + k);

       my_data.question = question_k.find('#question-text').val();
       my_data.answer_type = question_k.find('select').val();
       my_data.options = [];

       for (var j = 0; j < num_question_options[k]; j++) {
           var answer = question_k.find('#answer-' + j).val();
           if (answer !== '') {
               my_data.options.push(answer)
           }
       }
       my_data.num_options = my_data.options.length;
       data.questions.push(my_data)
   }
   return data
   }
   ```
6. **submit_data_create.js**

   ```
   $(document).ready(function (event) {
       $(document).on('submit', '#form', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var data = collect_data();
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '/form/create/',
               data: data,
               success: function (data, textStatus) {
                   window.location.href = '/form/list/'
               },
               fail: function (response) {
                   alert('Coś poszło nie tak.');
               }
           });
       })
   });
   ```

Comment: any ideas? Maybe you need more information?